# how to set button disable/enable only in the specific date in android?

Tags: java, android

My Problem in my project with a System Date and limit button Visibility.

So my question is:

How to set enable button only in the specific date?

Or in other words,

How to enable button if system date is (for ex.) 29 june 2014?

I read the Google API documentation but I don't know which of the following classes should be used and how it is used:

```
java.util.Date
```

or

```
Calendar.get(Calendar.DATE)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Date`, `Time`, or `Calendar`

Here is an example with `Calendar`:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
int dayOfMonth = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
if (month == Calendar.JUNE && dayOfMonth == 29 && year == 2014) {
  // June 29, 2014
  myButton.setEnabled(true);
}
else
{
  // NOT June 29, 2014
  myButton.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot. This Code is Solved My Problem. and with thank others

Answer (score 0):

First of all make date object and convert it into timezone, then after you got current date. Now, check if date is your specific date then set button to visible otherwise invisible.

Answer (score 0):

First of all on page load you have to compare a system date with your target date

like this

if you compare date given in your question than

```
if(curr.get(Calendar.DATE)==29 && curr.get(Calendar.MONTH)==5 && curr.get(Calendar.YEAR)==2014){
        //   Enable button
    }else{
          // Disable button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution,

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date1 = dateFormatter .parse("2009-12-31");
//Today's date here 
        Date date1 = dateFormatter .parse("2009-12-31");


Date specificDate = date1.getStartDate();
Date today = new Date();


String specificDate Str = dateFormatter.format(specificDate);
String todayStr = dateFormatter.format(date2);

if(specificDateStr.equals(todayStr)) {
    System.out.println("Both are equals");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save your target date on `sharedPreference` and on page load you can fetch the target date from sharedPreference. Obviously it will be on string so you need to convert it on Date formate using

You can convert String to Date like this:

```
String targetDate = "12/12/1912";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse(targetDate);
```

And back to String

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println("Date is : " + formatter.format(date));
```

then you can compare your target date with current system date by using

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("2009-12-31");
Date date2 = sdf.parse("2010-01-31");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date1));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date2));
if(date1.compareTo(date2)==0){
    enableButton();
}else{
    diableButton();
}
```

Hope it might help